# Unable to properly format '\n' to allow a new line to begin with '$'

Tags: python, syntax

I was writing a simple annual salary calculation and I discovered I am unable to start a new line with '$' while using the '\n' escape character.

This is what I've been trying to re-work;

```
monthlyPay = 5000
annualPay = monthlyPay * 12
print(
    "Your annual pay is: \n
    $",
    format(annualPay, ',.2f')
    )
```

Comment: Include the error so we can more quickly spot the problem.

Comment: `print(f"Your annual pay is:\n${annualPay:.2f}")`

Comment: to split a string to multiples lines use a triple quote: `"""..."""`

Comment: Sorry for the late response, thank you! The triple quotes helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
monthlyPay = 5000
annualPay = monthlyPay * 12
print(
    "Your annual pay is: \n $",
    format(annualPay, ',.2f')
    )
```

Hello, I can output correctly using the above format in pycharm

Maybe there shouldn't be a newline before $

Answer (score 1):

You cannot break a normal string like that. Either use `\n` in a single line, or a triple-quoted string. Any of the following will work

```
print(
    "Your annual pay is: \n$",
    format(annualPay, ',.2f')
    )

print(
    """Your annual pay is:
$""",
    format(annualPay, ',.2f')
    )
```

If you really want to use a normal string, but want it broken into two lines, you can use the fact that two string literals written next to each other, only separated by whitespace, are equivalent to their concatenation, i.e. `"abc" "def"` is equivalent to `"abcdef"`:

```
print(
    "Your annual pay is: \n"
    "$",
    format(annualPay, ',.2f')
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Newlines are significant in python - depending on context, they may signal the end of a programming statement. Like many languages, python has a way to "escape" characters like newline and tab that would otherwise be difficult to write in a program.

In your case, you properly used the `\n` escape for newlines, but then violated the rules for the actual newline you used to separate lines in the print. Since that real newline is inside of a single expression defining a parameter for the function call, real newlines are fine. Just add some quotes so that you no longer violate the rule that string literals cannot have real newlines.

```
monthlyPay = 5000
annualPay = monthlyPay * 12
print(
    "Your annual pay is: \n"
    "$",
    format(annualPay, ',.2f')
    )
```

Alternately, python has a triple-quoted literal string that *does* allow newlines. You can use it instead of the escape character.

```
monthlyPay = 5000
annualPay = monthlyPay * 12
print(
    """Your annual pay is:
$""",
    format(annualPay, ',.2f')
    )
```

More commonly, one uses python's f-strings which embed the formatting in the string.

```
monthlyPay = 5000
annualPay = monthlyPay * 12
print(f"Your annual pay is: \n${annualPay:.2f}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
monthlyPay = 500
annualPay = monthlyPay * 12

#you can use f-string in >3.6 python versions
print(f"Your annual pay is:\n${annualPay:,.2f}")
```